# Get SelectedItem of ComboBox Bound Multi-Colum List

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have a multi-column `List` bound to a `ComboBox`.

It displays List Column `Name` as the `ItemSource`.

[image: cbo]

---

**Problem**

`SelectedItem` does return the `Name`.

With `MessageBox.Show(vm.cboVideoQuality_SelectedItem);` the `string` shows as `MyProgram.ViewModel+VideoQuality` instead of `High`.

I tried filtering `Name` with:
`vm.cboVideoQuality_SelectedItem.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name);`

But it gives error `'char' does not contain definition for Name`.

---

**XAML**

Bind `Item Source` and `Selected Item`.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboVideoQuality" 

          ItemsSource="{Binding cboVideoQuality_Items, Mode=TwoWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"

          SelectedItem="{Binding cboVideoQuality_SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedValuePath="Name"

          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Margin="0,0,0,0" 
          Width="100" />
```

---

**ViewModel**

```
// Item Source
//
public class VideoQuality
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Bitrate { get; set; }
}

public List<VideoQuality> _cboVideoQuality_Items = new List<VideoQuality>()
{
     new ViewModel.VideoQuality() { Name = "High",   Bitrate = "5000K" },
     new ViewModel.VideoQuality() { Name = "Medium", Bitrate = "2500K" },
     new ViewModel.VideoQuality() { Name = "Low",    Bitrate = "500K" },
};

public List<VideoQuality> cboVideoQuality_Items
{
    get { return _cboVideoQuality_Items; }
    set
    {
        _cboVideoQuality_Items = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("cboVideoQuality_Items");
    }
}


// Selected Item
//
public string _cboVideoQuality_SelectedItem { get; set; }
public string cboVideoQuality_SelectedItem
{
    get { return _cboVideoQuality_SelectedItem; }
    set
    {
        if (_cboVideoQuality_SelectedItem == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _cboVideoQuality_SelectedItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("cboVideoQuality_SelectedItem");
    }
}
```

---

**C#**

I cannot check if `selected = "High"` because `SelectedItem` does not equal `Name`.

It equals `MyProgram.ViewModel+VideoQuality`.

```
ViewModel vm = mainwindow.DataContext as ViewModel;

string selected = vm.cboVideoQuality_SelectedItem;

if (selected == "High")
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already used `SelectedValuePath` and should of course also use `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem`:

```
<ComboBox
      ItemsSource="{Binding cboVideoQuality_Items}"
      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
      SelectedValuePath="Name"
      SelectedValue="{Binding cboVideoQuality_SelectedItem}" .../>
```

---

As a note, in both Bindings `Mode=TwoWay` is redundant. An ItemsSource binding is never two-way, while a SelectedValue binding is two-way by default.

I'd also recommend not to use binding target property details in view model property names. E.g. `cboVideoQuality_SelectedItem` should just be `SelectedVideoQuality`. Thus you may also bind it to the SelectedValue property of a ListBox or even the Text property of a TextBlock without too much confusion.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. I will also rename the model properties.